Nginx is not working outside local network
I have a node.js server with express that serves an https web. The server is runing Windows 10. I have configured a no-ip ddns with ssl certificates. The web is on port 3000 and I want to start a reverse proxy with nginx to access it without having to specify the port, just the domain name. The problem is that nginx is working for local network machines but not external ones. This is the config for nginx:
worker_processes 1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name servidordelacruz.dynns.com;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name xxxxxx.dynns.com;

        ssl_certificate      route_to\cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  route_to\cert.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

I have ports 80 and 443 open on the router for the server and just for testing the windows firewall is disabled entirely.
I also confirmed the ddns is working since I also have a minecraft server that is accesible.
In the access.log file I can also see that the phone reaches the server:
X.X.X.X - - [05/Nov/2024:20:52:40 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 15; Mobile; rv:132.0) Gecko/132.0 Firefox/132.0"

Finally, in the errors. log file I see this error constantly:
2024/11/05 21:05:46 [info] 5276#10252: *943 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000412:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate:SSL alert number 42) while SSL handshaking, client: X.X.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:443

The client IP is my own public IP. I read that it might not be important though.

You need to specify fullchain certificate as ssl_certificate parameter. Such questions should be asked at ServerFault rather than StackOverflow.

I tried to specify the fullchain certificate but it did not work. I will ask the question in ServerFault, thanks!

Specifying single certificate rather than fullchain one definitely won't work. I see you trying to proxy to localhost:3000 via https, maybe this is also an error.

Such should be asked on Server Fault. Besides, you might use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the TLS handshake packets, and there the cause should be clear.

@IvanShatsky I tried the fullchain and it did not work either. Why may it be an error to proxy to localhost:3000 via https? it is a web server that i created in node.js using the https packages using the same certificates I am trying to use in nginx, maybe that is the problem?

You should look at the proxy_ssl_name directive documentation, however since default proxy_ssl_server_name value if off it is unlikely a cause of your problem. Anyway, proxying HTTPS to HTTPS via loopback interface makes a little sense, it's only an extra overhead, encrypting and decrypting again incoming packets. Common approach is leave SSL termination (as well as serving static content, if possible) to nginx. Well, lets move to [SF] to continue.

One more thing worth to mention. Using a valid cert-only file as the ssl_certificate parameter should not result in such an error, it can only lead to certificate validation failure (e.g. if you are using Let's encrypt certificate and your browser CA does not include the R10/R11 certificates), so my first assumption was incorrect. However I was not able to connect to your domain via HTTPS 443 TCP port (connection via plain HTTP port 80 is ok).
